# Problema TypeError: tags.setArticulos tags is not a function

Tags: nodejs, sequelize.js

Me aparece este error cuando intento realizar agregar una relación desde el *postman*:

> TypeError: tags.setArticulos tags is not a function

Este es el código que utilizo:

```
var db = require('../relations');
var articulos = db.articulos;
var tags = db.tags;

var ex = module.exports = {};

ex.create = function (req, res, next) {

    var data = req.body;
    articulos.create(data)
            .then(function () {
                res.status(200).jsonp({msj: 'SUCCESS!'});
            });
};

ex.crearTags = function(req, res, next){
   var id=req.params.id;
   var data =req.body;
    tags.findById(id)
      .then(function(tags){
          return tags.setArticulosTags(req.body.IdArticulos)
      })
      .then(res.send.bind(res))
      .catch(next)
};

  ex.artag = function(req, res, next){
    var data = req.body;
      tags.create(data,{
        include:[
          {
            model: tags
          }
        ]
      }).then(function(result){
          res.status(200).jsonp(result);
      });
  };
```

Esta es el de la ruta:

```
  var express = require('express');
var routeArticulos = express.Router();

var x = require("../controllers/controllerArticulos");

routeArticulos.route('/data/articulos')
        .get(x.read)
        .post(x.create);

routeArticulos.route('/data/crearTags/:id')
            .put(x.crearTags)
            .post(x.artag);

routeArticulos.route('/data/articulos/:id')
        .get(x.read)
        .put(x.update)
        .delete(x.delete);

module.exports = routeArticulos;
```

Comment: Cuando preguntes no olvides poner las etiquetas de la parte de tu código que genera el problema; en este caso, es *Sequelize*.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner los modelos?

Comment: Gracias amigo ya quedo solucionado (y)